# ImageResizer: Resize based on filename

Tags: imageresizer

Instead of specifying width and height in the querystring like this:

```
http://example.com/media/cow/small.png?w=100&h=100
```

Is it possible to configure Imageresizer to look at the filename (small.png) and use this information to scale it to 100x100?

This would allow me to request images like this:

```
http://example.com/media/cow/small.png
http://example.com/media/cow/big.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually called URL rewriting. See

- [Using ImageResizer with a custom naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774853/using-imageresizing-with-a-custom-naming-convention)
- [How can I set up custom ImageResizer URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299837/how-can-i-set-up-custom-imageresizer-urls/11300150#11300150)
- [Web.config rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592327/imageresizer-web-config-rewrite-rule-not-working-properly)
- [UrlRewrite IIS to make existing image urls work with ImageResizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522000/urlrewrite-iis-to-make-existing-image-urls-work-with-imageresizer/18561149#18561149)
- [ImageResizer custom urls for bundled effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287881/imageresizer-custom-urls-for-bundled-effects)

We also define a `Config.Pipeline.Defaults` event to let people change default settings. It's just like URL rewriting, but provides 'default' behavior and only affects processed images.

Comment: Works like a charm writing my own plugin. Very easy to do