# bgcolor in web.config?

Tags: imageresizer

is it possible to change the default bgcolor by web.config and without presets?

or, even with presets, is there a way for a preset to be a default one? I would like to keep URL short therefore not include the preset name

Comment: [Duplicate, see these six questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28070477/166893).

Comment: @NathanaelJones I dont see where bgcolor is mentioned there

Comment: I see what you mean. Isnt there an easier way? just a web.config way to override the value?

Comment: Not at this time. You can use URL rewriting in web.config, but you may end up being forced to use 3 lines of C#/VB/F# to get exactly the result you want.